# Ceylon compiler and VM

Tags: compiler-construction, ceylon, vm-implementation

Are there any Ceylon specific VMs? Or do all available ceylon compilers produce JVM bytecode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently (two years later), there are production-ready compilers for the JVM and JavaScript. There are also two community-driven projects to create compilers for:

- the Dart VM, and
- LLVM.

The success of these community-driven projects will depend a lot upon how much community interest and contribution they attract.

Answer (score 2):

Ceylon isn't complete yet, but from what I understand it is intended to be first and foremost a language specification more than a specific compiler implementation, so that what it compiles to is flexible.

To demonstrate its target code agnosticism, Ceylon currently is developing reference compilers to the jvm and also to javascript.

Comment: I think that the intent is for Ceylon to become a real programming language suitable for developing production systems on a range of platforms.  The fact that the current implementations are not performant should not be taken as intent.  (As they say ... "Rome was not built in a day".)

Comment: Obviously though, this will depend on how much effort is sunk into the project by various people.  And there is always a "chicken and egg" problem  with new languages - resources are attracted to success, but success requires resources.

Comment: so are you interested in it sir? @StephenC

Comment: @Elltz - Interested in what?  In what respect?